# Excel - table insert new row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

We have a table with formulas in individual columns. When we copy and insert a new row, some of the columns populate with the above formula however some do not. It's unclear to us why this happens, if any one can clear this head scratcher up, would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: [Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: this happens if - for some reason - you changed one cell in the column individually: save the formula as text somewhere else, select the column, delete everything and reapply the formula - it should then work as expected